# Depuracion de aplicaciones android

Tags: android, hash, depuración, md5

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy depurando una aplicacion android para conectarme a su api, cuando la aplicacion realiza las consultas veo que carga los datos desde una api publica, pero algunos de ellos, normalemente las url estan hasheadas parece ser md5, es posible leerlo en el navegador?

Mendiante Fiddler logre obtener las url directas a la api, la siguiente url contiene las categorias de la aplicacion:

```
http://tv.iptvmanagerpro.com/apiv2/channel_by_id/?id=1&mode=md5&av=20190529
```

Si quitamos de la url la palabra &mode=md5 extrae los datos pero no todos, como se puede ver en data esta encryptada pero no se en que algoritmo, quiero ver si son los url directos, como podria leerlos en el navegador? porque la aplicacion los obtiene de aqui:

```
http://tv.iptvmanagerpro.com/apiv2/channel_by_id/?id=1&av=20190529
```

tambien mire que al conectarme al contenido en el reproductor de la aplicacion se ejecutan tres url seguidos que si le quitan el texto "&mode=md5" retorna un hash que no se puede leer parace ser que consulta informacion:

```
[http://providers.iptvmanagerpro.com/get_module.php?module=comparator&mode=md5][1]

[http://ht.iptvmanagerpro.com/get_module.php?module=providers&mode=md5][1]

[http://providers.iptvmanagerpro.com/get_module.php?module=providers.totalplay&mode=md5][1]
```

Espero puedan contribuir a entender el funcionamiento y como oculta los datos, el fin de esto es meramente educativo y por curiosidad

Comment: El problema es que ese hash md5 puede estar combinado con otro hash que no sea md5, lo que hace mucho mas duro algo asi.

Comment: como se podria determinar? llevo horas analizandolo y no logro dar con la respuesta

Comment: Hace poco me encontre con un video acerca de eso, sin embargo si no estoy mal solo es posible por medio de php, checa este video a ver si sirve de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQgA13fGPOc El lo hace por medio de un archivo externo en el que estan guardados los valores a desencriptar, pero creo que podrias modificar el codigo para que use los valores traidos desde la API.